# Pattern to render multiple coffee

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have a `task` model which is related to the `user` and `project` models.

When I create/update a task, I need to do an update in the view async, not only for the task change/addition, but to the project and user info (because some of that data might change too).

I have this in the controller:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(params[:task])
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And my tasks/create.js.coffee

```
# Update task table
$('#mytable').append("<%= j render(partial: 'tasks/task', locals: { t: @task }) %>")

# Update user data
$('.user-data').html("<%= j render(partial: 'users/user_widget', locals: { u: current_user }) %>")

# Update project data
$('.project-data').html("<%= j render(partial: 'projects/project_widget', locals: { p: @project }) %>")
```

And it works great. I see 2 issues:

- In every render of `.js.coffee` I add, I am repeating the code too much. I duplicate exactly the same code for updating project and user data, on tasks update, tasks destroy, and I would do the same for a new model which might affect the user and the project
- It seems weird to handle project and user data in tasks/create.js.coffee

Therefore, I am looking for a better pattern to handle this stuff, any ideas?

**EDIT (to clarify):**
I think achieving something like this would be better:

*tasks/create.js.coffee*

```
# Update task table
$('#mytable').append("<%= j render(partial: 'tasks/task', locals: { t: @task }) %>")

UserData.refresh()
ProjectData.refresh()
```

However, I can't do that because I need to render the partial each time, so I would have to do something weird like passing the html partial to those `refresh()` functions, and it would be pretty the same as the previous way.
This is just a way that came to my mind, but I would like to hear your ideas if any.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. What are you trying to avoid?

Comment: I am trying to avoid these 2 issues I am describing at the post: Not repeating code to update the project and user data in every coffee of those models related to project and user. And not having the responsibility of updating user and project in the task js. These issues are very related though

Comment: @DaveNewton See my edit, it might clarify things a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be interested in an answer to this issue, I found the **Garber-Irish pattern** as a great solution to my problem.

You can read more about this here:
https://www.viget.com/articles/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution

There is even a gem: https://github.com/tonytonyjan/gistyle

Using this pattern, you can have execution contexts for your HTTP requests. So for example you can have an `afterCreate()` method on each js controller and depending where your HTTP Request was created, you can trigger a different event.

This allows to use polymorphic answers to update the view.

Answer (score 1):

You could render a template/action that belongs to a different controller.  So you could keep the tasks/create.js.coffee file and for all the other controller actions (like users and projects) that use the same code, in your respond_to block you would use:

```
format.json { render 'tasks/create' }
```

You could even render a specific file:

```
format.json { render file: "path/to/specific/file" }
```

Here is a link with more information on rendering in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller

Comment: I know that, but it wouldn't solve my issue, given it's what I am doing already. My code is rendering the task/create.js.coffee. The problem is that this file is taking care of multiple view updates which are not fully related to the task. However, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  The only other way that I can think of to handle this is to have the controller respond with the json information (instead of rendering javascript) and use the jQuery ajax success callback to update the information on the page.  Then you would have one file to handle all the page updates. You could even create common functions like the `UserData.refresh()` and `ProjectData.refresh()` but its all in javascript instead of through the controller rendering.  I don't think the way you're doing it now is that bad or unconventional, these are just other options.